# Protractor verify the button clicked or not

Tags: selenium-webdriver, protractor, angularjs-e2e

In my page, there is a submit button used for push data.
Before all the data fill in.
It is like below:

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning disabled" ng-class="{disabled:!(deployenv.selected.name&amp;&amp;deployinv_pf.selected.name&amp;&amp;step.selected)}" ng-click="deploySubmit()" tabindex="0">Submit</button>
```

After all the data filled in.
It changes to below:

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning" ng-class="{disabled:!(deployenv.selected.name&amp;&amp;deployinv_pf.selected.name&amp;&amp;step.selected)}" ng-click="deploySubmit()" tabindex="0">Submit</button>
```

We could see the only different here is the "**`disabled`**", so I wrote the spec to verify the button is not available before any data fill in.

```
expect(element(by.css('button:not(.disabled)')).isPresent()).toBe(false);
```

But I am not sure why it always return `true` instead of `false`.

> Message:    Expected true to be false.
>   Stacktrace:    Error: Failed expectation

Can some one help to research once?

Comment: Try opening your page in chrome and type `$('button:not(.disabled)')` in the console. Is the selector acting as expected?

Comment: @QhAuth, thanks for the hint. I tried your way, it return 2 button element. Then I tried to add another attribute like `expect(element(by.css('button:not(.disabled)[ng-click="deploySubmit()"]')).isPresent()).toBe(false);  `.It works now